# CakePHP Failing Custom Rule Validation (regex)

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I'm following a Lynda.com course for CakePHP 2.4.0 and per the material the following code should work but fails with the latter error message:

```
    public $validate = array(
        'publication_name' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/([\w.-]+ )+[\w+.-]/'),
                'message' => 'The publication name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
            )
        ),
    );
```

"preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [CORE/Cake/Model/Validator/CakeValidationRule.php, line 281]".

Per my searching, the regex should work as it is using a non-alphanumeric delimiter (/). I'm quite perplexed to say the least.

The only way I have been able to get it to successfully save the record is by removing the custom validation rule (which is not the desired result for a variety of reasons).

Any insight on why this is failing validation? I've diff'd my code against that of the author's exercise files and am not sure what I'm (most likely) over looking...

Thank you in advance for your time and insight. I truly appreciate it.

Source Code for Model, View and Controllers: http://tny.cz/0a995577

Comment: And you _are_ using CakePHP 2.4.0? In that case, the rule you are showing there would normally never be processed on [Line 281](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.0/lib/Cake/Model/Validator/CakeValidationRule.php#L281) of `CakeValidationRule.php`, that's were rules like `'words' => 'string value'` are processed. The regex is totally fine (syntax wise), it must be something else. You'll need to show some more of the involved code, controller action, model, etc...

Comment: I'm going to diff my project files against that of the author's code now. I've been using cake bake, which shows that it's using the app/Console/bake for 2.4.0, but I also have an installation of 2.4.1 so I may have accidentally baked some code using the wrong bake console... I will update this shortly. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Pastebin is currently offline due to load, so here is an alternative that shows the full source for the Model, App Controller and Publications Controller, and Add View. http://tny.cz/0a995577 I'm more than glad to provide any other source code as necessary in order to determine why the rule is failing. Thanks again.

Comment: Oddly enough, the validation was failing due to isUnique being spelled incorrectly. However, due to the regex directly above the isUnique rule I had assumed it was the custom rule the was failing. With that error being fixed, it no longer shows the preg_match error message. Although, the custom rule is still providing the validation error message and is failing to save to the DB.

Comment: I used Meld to diff the entire project files against the author's source code and there is no difference between either of them. Furthermore, I did the diff from the root directory structure (including app/lib/vendors/plugins, et al) in the diff to ensure that there wasn't a version difference due to accidentally using the wrong cake bake console and it still fails validation. I'm sure this is something incredibly simple that I'm overlooking (as it has happened all too often in the past) but I'm not sure what the next step would be in the debug process. :(

Comment: I decided to start from scratch and remove the other versions of Cake that were on my system; furthermore, I made sure I added the Cake bake console into my PATH to ensure that I'm consistently using the correct bake console. And, instead of extracting the 2.4.0.zip archive into a directory and directly working from there, I extracted it to /var/www and used bake to create the project in the web root. This should ensure that everything is using the appropriate settings going forward and hopefully resolve the issue. I'll update this when I'm done and mark this resolved if it does fix the error.

Comment: Even after starting from scratch and rewriting the validation rules, it still fails with the provided error message for the custom validation rule... Any suggestions on where else to look or how to further proceed with troubleshooting this problem? It doesn't seem to be a framework error, but a simple failed validation. I provided 'a', 'A', and 'Lynda' (without single quotes) as the publication name and it fails.

Comment: I just setup the provided Exercise Files to use my DB connection and tested the field validation with the author's provided source code and it fails authentication.

Comment: What do mean with it "_fails with the provided error message_"? Are you talking about a validation error, or a PHP error? The regex will not match `Lynda` in case that's what you are talking about: http://regex101.com/r/dA0pH9 It matches one or more words (including `.` and `-`) separated by a single space, followed by a single word char (again including `.` and `-`). Also it allows to prepend and append arbitrary chars, as it doesn't make use of `^` and `$`.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for introducing me to such an amazing tool; it is incredibly useful and valuable! Also, I'd like to thank your for answering my question as I now understand why the field validation was failing and the 'message' was being displayed to the user upon submission. 'Lynda' does not match the regex that I have specified, but 'Lynda dot com' does. So, I need to tweak my regex so that one word, multiple words, including numbers and spaces will all be valid input. Normally I'd chalk this up as an ID10T error, but this time it was pure ignorance. Thanks for the help and insight!

Comment: @ndm, please submit your final remarks as an answer, so that I may mark this as solved and give you credit. I'd still be confused if it wasn't for your clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the regex itself is syntactically correct, so it won't cause such an error. As you figured it was a typo in a different rule causing the problem.

However the rule also won't validate as expected (http://regex101.com/r/dA0pH9), as the regex matches one or more words (including `.` and `-`) separated by a single space, followed by a single word char (again including `.` and `-`). Also it allows to prepend and append arbitrary chars, as it doesn't make use of `^` and `$`.

To make it match your requirements

> one word, multiple words, including numbers and spaces

try something like this:

```
/^(\w ?)+(?<! )$/
```

That would match one or more words (which may consist of numbers only, and may be only 1 char in length), separated by a space, not allowing a trailing space.

Though it would also match something like `1 2 3 4 5` (http://regex101.com/r/kK3jG9/), which might not be applicable, so you may want to refine it, for example by requiring at least 1 letter per word, with a minimum length of 3 chars:

```
/^((?=\d*[a-z])\w{3,} ?)+(?<! )$/i
```

A quick breakdown:

```
(
  (?=\d*[a-z])  # the word must contain at least one letter
  \w{3,} ?      # a word with at least 3 chars, optionally followed by a space
)+              # one or more times
(?<! )          # no trailing space allowed
```